# Integer division instead of regular one in Python

Tags: python-2.7, division

I have this simple code:

`[n/2 for n in range(100, 200)]`

But, strangely enough, it returns [50,50,51,51,52,52,etc], so it uses integer division instead of normal one (I need it to output [50,50.5,51,51.5,etc]) Why is it happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, dividing 2 integers will always produce an integer. (In Python 3, you get "real" division)

You can rewrite your code as:

```
[n/2.0 for n in range(100, 200)]
```

or in the case where you have 2 variables:

```
[float(n)/othervar for n in range(100, 200)]
```

to get the expected behavior,

or add

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the start of the file to get the Python 3 behavior now.

To answer the "why" part of the question, this is a holdover from C's division semantics (although Python made the choice to always floor the result instead of rounding toward 0, so you don't even get the true C integer division semantics.)

Comment: Nice contribution with the `__future__` module.

Comment: Yeah, apparently I have to use n/(variable+0.00). That works, but it's not looking good.

Comment: @RomaValcer: edited my answer. use `float()` on either of the variables rather than adding `0.00` to force one to be a float.

Comment: yeah, looks much better. Anyways, sometimes python dynamic typization (if I chose right word) can cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[n/2.0 for n in range(100, 200)]` to make it a float operation. By passing `2` as an integer and all numbers in the range as an integer Python is treating the result as an integer. You need `Floating Point Arithmetic`. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for more details.